# How to validate if PO Detail quantity exceed in PoOrder quantity?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

My question is, 
how to validate first the quantity in PoDetail table before adding new data 
if the quantity is exceed in PoOrder table?
if im right this is a business rule that i want to create.
I'm using asp.net mvc 4,EF code first and repository pattern.

here is a sample data.

```
INSERT INTO PoOrders
SELECT 1,'PO123',5000

INSERT INTO PoDetails
SELECT 1,1,2500
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,1,2000
```

If i try to add new PoDetail(e.g. Qty is 1000) it must show a
message or prevent adding new record.

The POCO class

```
public class PoOrder
{
    [Key]
    public int PoID { get; set; }

    public string PoNumber { get; set;}

    public int PoQty {get; set;}
 }

 public class PoDetail
 {
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Po_ID {get; set;}
    public int ReleaseQty { get; set;}

    [ForeignKey("Po_ID")]
    public virtual PoOrder PoOrders { get; set; }     
 }
```

Any tips or solution is very much appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it seems more appropriate for `PoOrder` to have a `PoDetails` collections. Supposing you change that, this would do what you want:

```
var query = 
    from o in PoOrders
    where o.PoId == orderId
    select new { o.PoQty, SumQty = o.PoDetails.Sum(d => d.ReleaseQty) };

var orderData = q.Single();
if (orderData.PoQty < orderData.SumQty + newQty)
    // message
```

where `orderId` and `newQty` are two variables containing the order's id and the quantity to be added, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @gert-arnold (Gert)! I forgot to include the collections
   
   [code] public virtual ICollection<PoDetail> PoDetails { get;   set; } [/code]